# How to save to local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

So I have made a table table elements and functions for the pop up and the form. Appending element on clicking save button also works. However I can't make it work the content to be stored and pulled from local storage in refresh page. I am somehow trying to populate the cell with currently generated ID . Considering the fact that I me new at JavaScript I am totally missing something Can someone give me idea what is that. The Code

```
 /*save to td */
 $('#save').click(function () {
    localStorage.setItem(clickID, JSON.stringify(clickID));
    var theName = $('input[name=name]').val();
    var theLastName = $('input[name=lastname]').val();
    $('input[name=name]').val("");
    $('input[name=lastname]').val("");
    var $fullCell = $('<p>' + theName + '' + theLastName +     '</p>');
    if((theLastName+theLastName).length > 0){
       $(callingID).append($fullCell);
       $(callingID).css('background-color', 'yellow');
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9zcj3ab8/27/

Comment: what is clickID - you probably need to understand what JSON.stringify does and what it expects as arguments when you call it

Answer (score 0):

In javascript keys for an object must be strings. You can think of localStorage as a persistent Javascript object. Since you are calling JSON.stringify on `clickID` I am assuming `clickID` is a javascript object.

The first argument to setItem must be a string, followed by any valid js type for the second argument (documentation for setItem here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem)

If clickID is a string:

Additionally, you are saving to localStorage just clickID and a stringified version of clickID. It seems to me that the intended behavior is to store to localStorage a string called clickID as a key (first argument) with the first name and last name as the value (second argument).

Not sure if that is the wrong jsfiddle but your `$('#save').click` function is nowhere to be found there.